# How to get a return message to slack

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, slack

I am setting up a / command in slack through google sheets and the return is a mess, but I think I am doing something wrong with the code but I can not figure out what.

```
function doPost(e) {
    if (typeof e !== 'undefined') {
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
        sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue(JSON.stringify(e));
    }
    return ContentService.createTextOutput('Thank you for your whitelist input! You rock! :kea: 
   :tada:');
}
```

The response is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel="shortcut icon" href="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/favicon.ico"><title>Error</title><style type="text/css">body {background-color: #fff; margin: 0; padding: 0;}.errorMessage {font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold; line-height: 150%; padding-top: 25px;}</style></head><body style="margin:20px"><div><img alt="Google Apps Script" src="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/logo.png"></div><div style="text-align:center;font-family:monospace;margin:50px auto 0;max-width:600px">The script completed but did not return anything.</div></body></html>
```

Rather than the Thank you message, I am just trying to get it to return the thank you message

Answer (score 1):

> notice: in case I am wrong with the interpretation, let me know and the answer will be updated

**Problem**

> Stringifying the whole event object instead of a specific parameter

**Update**

After the discussion, I was able to find out that the issue was, for the most part, related to the behaviour of the `/exec` endpoint - the solution is to update the script version for the latest code snapshot to become available for incoming requests.

**Generic Solution**

When a request is made to a Web App that has a `doPost` function declared with POST method, the event object is constructed automatically and has the following structure at the time of writing:

Event object structure

```
| Property      | Type   |
| ------------- | ------ |
| queryString   | String |
| parameter     | Object |
| parameters    | Object |
| contextPath   | String |
| contentLength | Number |
| postData      | Object |
```

`postData` property structure

```
| Property | Type   |
| -------- | ------ |
| length   | Number |
| type     | String |
| contents | String |
| name     | String |
```

The data you actually need should definitely be contained in `parameter`, `parameters` or `postData` depending on your solution.

**Optimizations**

1. You don't have to check for `e` to be undefined for the reason explained above. In case you want to test your code by running in editor, separate the actual logic from the trigger (for example, move it to a function).

**References**

1. Web Apps event object [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters)

Comment: I know the Parameter part but I am not there yet this is the first big code that I have written and am trying to do the return message and then move to parameters which I will likely also need help with lol

Comment: Excuse me, but could you explain your comment - not sure I understand what you said at all?

Comment: So I am trying to get a return message to the user on slack, before I moved on to defining the parameters, doing it step by step I suppose. The parameters I might need help with but first I need to get it to return a proper message.

Comment: also thank you for all of your help you are awesome!

Comment: My apologies, but really not sure that I follow - it there a specific issue with that different from what you've posted as a question? Btw, it would help if you updated the question with what the "mess" looks like

Comment: I updated it I am so sorry I am trying never done this before and I have not coded in years

Comment: Ah, I see - thank you for updating. Which url endpoint do you use - `/exec` or `/dev`?

Comment: I think that is is /dev but I am not 100% where would I check this for you?

Comment: depends on how you call the script - it is either the url in search bar or the url you pass to the function that requests the Web App (not sure about your setup). The path at the end of the url should indicate which one you use. I mention it because it doesn't seem like it should return a "did not return anything" error, unless you either: 1. use /exec endpoint and forgot to version update; 2. try to load in browser and have a noop `doGet`

Comment: let me ask this, when I update it do I need to go into the slack app and update the link that google sheets gives me every time? and its /exec

Comment: No, in Slack you don't need to - as this path is just the route that runs your deployed code. But you need to increment the version and redeploy each time you make *any* change to the code if you use the /exec endpoint - otherwise despite you seing the updated code, the code actaully run will be the older one. Am I correct in my assumption that this is the case? Because if not, there is no reason why your code should not work

Comment: YOU ARE A GENIUS AND I ADORE YOU THANK YOU SO MUCH!! i MEAN... IT WORKED LOL

Comment: Well, that one is a very common problem (which also indicates that this design choice is confusing) - please read the [guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) - it will save you some debugging time in the future.